# How to create n variables in BASH?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, variables, csv

I'm trying to create n variables in bash...ideally an array with these n variables so that I may later go through and assign them to columns I read in from a csv file. I guess I'm just really confusing myself with syntax. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like what you need is an array.  Look up the section titled "Arrays" in the bash documentation.

Comment: Consider expanding your question with a small test case, including expected input types (1-2 lines of each), and expected output. Otherwise we really have to play 20 questions with you, which is only fun for the masochists ;-). Good luck.

Comment: To answer your question, you can create an array with 10 elements with `myarray=({1..10})`. Unfortunately, this won't help read CSV files in any way. If that's what you want, you should search or ask about that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in bash to read a line from a CSV file and put it into an array is:

```
IFS=, read -r -a ARRAY < filename
```

The `IFS=,` at the beginning tells `read` to use <kbd>,</kbd> as a field separator. The option `-a ARRAY` tells `read` to put the results in a bash array named `ARRAY` (you could use any name; it doesn't need to be uppercase).

You would normally want to do that in a loop, something like:

```
while IFS=, read -r -a ARRAY; do
  # do something with ARRAY
done < filename
```

This is not a very robust technique, since it will not work with quoted fields and especially not with embedded commas in quoted fields. There are CSV-parsing libraries for most languages; if you have any familiarity with Python, it might be a good choice.